# Beginning to use JUnit, how to run simple tests

Tags: java, junit

I have some code, similar to:

```
 public class Foo
 {
      private String Bar;

      public Foo(String _bar)
      {
           Bar = new String(_bar);
      }

      public String getBar() { return Bar; }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o)
      {
           if (o == this) return true;
           if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;

           Foo temp = (Foo)o;
           if (Bar == null) return (Bar==temp.Bar);
           return (Bar.equals(temp.Bar));
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode()
      {
           return Objects.hash(this.Bar);
      }
 }
```

I want to try to write a test case for this class which will test all my methods. I am also trying to grasp what a suite() method is and how to use TestRunner.

How would I begin to go about doing this?

Edit 1:  Fixed the error above

Also, a Test class

```
 public class FooTest
 {
      private FooTest ft;

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception
      {
           ft = new FooTest("baz");
      }

      @Test
      public void testGetFoo()
      {
           assertEquals(ft.getBar(),"baz");
      }

      @Test
      public void testEquals()
      {
            assertEquals(ft.equals(new Foo("baz")), true);
            assertEquals(ft.equals(new String("no")),false);
            assertEquals(ft.equals(ft), true);
            assertEquals(ft.equals(null),false);
      }
 }
```

I have come across this site (http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~djanzen/tdl/tddintro/helloworld/) which is very helpful. However, I am having issues with the portion of the code on the page under AllTests.java, specifically:

```
public static junit.framework.Test suite() 
{
   return new JUnit4TestAdapter(AllTests.class);
}
```

In eclipse, I get the following error message:

```
 The method JUnit4TestAdapter(Class<Foo>) is undefined for the type AllTests
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Thank you, that is a good resource but it is very thin and is not very helpful is understanding what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Héctor you need to start with the simple stuff, and build from there.  Try looking at https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Your code needs some "work" - your public equals(Object o) method is missing a "boolean" - public boolean equals(Object o).    I also noticed that you were using underscores in your variables "_bar".  You need  consistent variable naming.

Comment: I found a decent explanation that covers testrunner and suite but it is giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Junit test, which exercises your code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testFooIsNotNull() {
        Foo myFoo = new Foo("Bar");
        assertNotNull(myFoo);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFooBarEqualsBar() {
        Foo myFoo = new Foo("bar");
        assertEquals("bar", myFoo.getBar());
    }
```

I am testing that myFoo is not NULL, and "bar" equals myFoo.getBar()

I fixed your code, so the equals Override worked:

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Foo {

    private String Bar;

    public Foo(String bar) {
        Bar = new String(bar);
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return Bar;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) 
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Foo))
            return false;

        Foo temp = (Foo)o;
        if (Bar == null) 
            return (Bar==temp.Bar);

        return (Bar.equals(temp.Bar));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.Bar);
    }
}
```

**Your code need further work.**  But the simple unit tests work.